# How to use texture from TextureAtlas in libgdx 3D

Tags: android, libgdx

I'm trying to move from individual textures to using a texture atlas for my boxes (they all show individual letters for a Scrabble-like game). I'm stuck with this, all the examples I find are for 2D sprites.

How do I create and assign the material to a 3D surface with the right mapping coordinates from an AtlasRegion?

```
public void createModelInstance(TextureAtlas letterAtlas) {
   AtlasRegion region = letterAtlas.findRegion(this.textureID);
   Material mat = new Material(???);
   modelInstance = new ModelInstance(modelTile); 
   modelInstance.nodes.get(0).parts.get(0).material.set(mat);
}
```

When used individual files for each texture this worked:

```
Material mat = new Material(TextureAttribute.createDiffuse(
    assetManager.get("textures/" + textureFile, Texture.class));
```

The surface is created:

```
MeshPartBuilder tileBuilder;
tileBuilder = modelBuilder.part("top", GL10.GL_TRIANGLES, Usage.Position | Usage.Normal | Usage.TextureCoordinates, new Material(ColorAttribute.createDiffuse(Color.WHITE)));
tileBuilder.rect(-0.45f, 0.1f, 0.45f,   0.45f, 0.1f, 0.45f,    0.45f, 0.1f, -0.45f,  -0.45f, 0.1f, -0.45f,  0f, 1f, 0f);
...
```

Comment: If you need texture you may get texture from TextueAtlas.getTexture also you can pass texture to custom shader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is currently not possible to use a `TextureAtlas` in this way. The only possible way to create a `TextureAttribute` is by supplying a `Texture`. A texture is a standalone `PixMap`.

`TextureRegion` in contrast describes an area of a bigger `Texture`. Currently there seems to be no way to create a `Texture` from a `TextureRegion` in the API. `TextureRegion.getTexture()` will only retrieve the full texture of the atlas it came from.

And it actually makes sense that the API doesn't offer such a conversion, because it destroys the purpose of the atlas. By making all regions individual textures, you wouldn't gain any performance anymore.

`TextureAttribute` currently seems to lack the support for texture atlasses completely, otherwise it would have to offer methods with `TextureRegion`s instead of `Textures`.

Comment: This is no longer the case. All factory methods now have a `TextureRegion` version, and there is a general purpose constructor that takes a type and a `TextureRegion`.